# sql loop through a list and insert records into column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to loop through a list and insert each item into a column and iterate 1000 time. I am SQL noob - can anyone help me with this?

What I have so far:

```
DECLARE @Counter INT 
DECLARE @myList varchar(100)

SET @Counter = 0
SET @myList = 'temp,humidity,dewpoint'

WHILE (@Counter <= 1000)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [DBO].[tbl_var] (VariableNames)
    VALUES (@myList)

    SET @Counter  = @Counter  + 1
END
```

I get this error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'VariableNames', table 'master.DBO.tbl_var'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

What I expected

`VariableNames` column

```
1. temp
2. humidity
3. dewpoint
4. temp
5. humidity
6. dewpoint
```

and so on until 1000 iterations of list is complete

Comment: Why do you want to loop at all? SQL is a set based language, so why not use a set based solution?

Comment: Also your expected result *suggests* you want one row per value, but your attempt uses a delimited value; which is it you actually want? Storing delimited data in your database, however, is a significant design flaw and you *should not* be doing it; use a normalised approach.

Comment: Finally, don't work in the `master` system database; I strongly suggest you `CREATE` (if you haven't already) a user database and then connect to that. Then `CREATE` and work with *your* objects in there. Don't create user objects in the system databases unless you have *very good* reasons to do so.

Comment: The code that you posted is it the actual code you are using that produce the error `column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.`,  there is no way you are getting that error message when `@myList` has a value

Comment: @Larnu want one row per value as an outcome. Using SQL Server Express LocalDB so that's why using master. using loop because want to generate a bunch of test data for some work am doing. for example get variable names in than can create some values and timestamps for each reading.

Comment: *"Using SQL Server Express LocalDB so that's why using master"* That isn't a reason to use the `master` database. LocalDB and Express both support user databases. This is like saying that you used a hammer to put a screw in the wall because you were already holding the hammer, even though the screwdriver was right there with on your toolbelt.

Comment: @Squirrel double-checked and defo running the code posted.  that's why I am so confused myList  has a value so shouldn't be getting that

Comment: @Larnu ok noted not to use master, thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to `INSERT` each value 1000 times then use a `VALUES` table construct and `CROSS JOIN` to a tally containing 1,000 rows. I use an inline tally in the solution below:

```sql
USE YourUserDatabase;
GO

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3) --1,000 rows
INSERT INTO dbo.tbl_var (VariableNames)
SELECT V.VariableName
FROM (VALUES('temp'),
            ('humidity'),
            ('dewpoint'),
            ('temp'),
            ('humidity'),
            ('dewpoint'))V(VariableName)
     CROSS JOIN Tally T;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested but this should work. You can use STRING_SPLIT function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

```
   DECLARE @Counter INT =1
    DECLARE @myList varchar(100)    
    SET @Counter=1
    SET @myList = 'temp,humidity,dewpoint'
    CREATE TABLE #TEMP (value varchar(255),cardinal Int)
    INSERT INTO #TEMP(value,cardinal)
    SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT(@myList, ',',1);

WHILE ( @Counter <= 1000)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO  [DBO].[tbl_var] (VariableNames)
    SELECT value from #TEMP WHERE cardinal =@counter
    SET @Counter  = @Counter  + 1
END
```